# Access object in the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have a `@minisets` model and a `@miniatures` model. They both `have_many` of each other through the `@contents` model.

As well as the foreign keys, the `@contents` model also has a `quantity` column.

From my `@minisets` show view I can show the associated `@miniatures` with the following:

```
<% @miniset.miniatures.each do |miniature| %>
      <%= link_to miniature.name, miniature %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to show the `quantity` entered for those miniatures but can't work out how to call information from the join table rather than the table it is joining.

Something like `<%= miniature.content.quantity %>` except that won't work. I assume the joining model must be in play for it to be supplying the joined info but how do I interact with it itself in that instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I need to be working with the join object in the instance variable rather than the joined object.

Find the `@contents` which belong to this `@miniset` and then get the `@miniature` info from there. Makes much more sense.

```
<% @miniset.contents.where(miniset_id: @miniset).each do |content| %>
          <%= link_to content.miniature.name, content.miniature %>
          x<%= content.quantity %>        
<% end %>
```

Found some very complicated answers to similar questions but this is dead simple. Hope it helps someone.